# Get path specified by a JFileChooser when saving

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a GUI that has a `JFileChooser`, and I need to use it for saving. I cannot find any method for getting the string in the user input box, I've tried `getFileSelected().getName()`, but this throws a `NullPointerException`.

I know I can get the directory the file chooser is pointing too, but my question is, how do I get the string of text that the user input so I can append it onto the path and write the file?

Comment: If `getSelectedFile` is throwing a `null` pointer exception then nothing has been selected by the user...

Comment: I want to get the text in the user input box, is that included in getSelectedFile? The theoretical file does not exist, it is only to be created.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                if (fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile());
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

You have to either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the file name field is selected or press the <kbd>Save</kbd> button...